# Peak detection in an array - problems with numpy dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to rewrite a peak detection method using nested for loops using numpy arrays instead. I previously posted the original code to reddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/lmsf1w/how_can_i_rewrite_a_nested_for_loop_using_numpy/

I'm very rusty with numpy and cant seem to get the method to work, the code is shown below; The input array is (257,5170) and windpw_size_r = 2

```
def numpy_separation(transformed_2d, window_size_r, k, window_size_s=1):
    # Array must be padded to allow a window size of 2
    pad = np.zeros((transformed_2d.shape[0], 1)) + np.vstack(transformed_2d[:, -1])
    while transformed_2d.shape[1] % 2 != 0:
        transformed_2d = np.append(transformed_2d, pad, axis=1)

    # Array reshaped into (1,2) tiles
    img_h, img_w = transformed_2d.shape
    tiled_array = transformed_2d.reshape(img_h//window_size_s, window_size_s,
                                img_w//window_size_r, window_size_r)
    tiled_array = tiled_array.swapaxes(1,2)

    # If range in (1,2) tile is greater than k*std peak present
    gamma = np.std(transformed_2d)
    filt = np.ptp(tiled_array, axis=3) < k * gamma
    A = tiled_array[filt]
    background_component = A.reshape((img_h, img_w))
    # Above line produces error message
    # ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1326632 into shape (257,5170)
    # Input array is (257,5170)

    foreground_component = transformed_2d - background_component
    return background_component, foreground_component
```

When I try and convert the array back to the original shape I get:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1326632 into shape (257,5170)
```

Basically there's 2058 points missing. Have I popped the data corresponding to peaks from the array? If so how can I set the peak windows to 0 and retain the original shape of the array?

Comment: Please post a properly indented [mcve] with inputs and complete error including traceback. But before you do that, make sure that you debug and docs on your own to figure out why the shape changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but remember that when you index an array, you're getting a subset of it. The root cause of the error you're having is here:

```
filt = np.ptp(tiled_array, axis=3) < k * gamma
A = tiled_array[filt] <----
background_component = A.reshape((img_h, img_w))
```

Try adding a `print(A.shape)` after the marked line; you'll see that the number of elements in A != number of elements in tiled array. Let me provide a much simpler example why:

```
B = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])
# B is an array of shape (3, 3)

filt = B > 5
# filt is a boolean array

print(filt)
# [[False False False]
#  [False False  True]
#  [ True  True  True]]


A = B[filt]
print(A)
# [6 7 8 9]
print(A.shape)
# (4,)
```

As you can see, A is no longer the same shape as B, because you've indexed it or applied a boolean mask.